# function not call when first click in jquery tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create UI with tabs.the tabs all contain seprate Forms.If i click the tabs the all form save function are call.For example for assumption if i fill the first tab form then i click second tab.then i refresh the page then i click the first tab.the datas are not saved.But after **i fill the first tab then click second and third tab continuously and refresh the page on third tab form then click to the first tab now the data are saved**.My problem is the function are not called single click immediately?

```
 $(".tab").tabs({
                selected: 0,
                select: function(e, ui) {

                        Firsttabvalue(arraytest);
                        Secondtabvalue(arraytest);
                        Thirdtabvalue(arraytest);

                        return true;

                }

            });
```

Comment: Instead of refreshing to see the result try to debug what's actually happening. No reason to perform the task "blindfolded" when you can look inside. This will either give you the answer or some context to put in your post help others to provide you the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you use jQueryUI tabs in your application (because you don't specify what exact plugin do you use). And if that's true, then if you look on page [jQueryUI API](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/) you'll get that there is no event "select" for tabs, only event "activate".

EDITED:
You may initialize tabs using that event:

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
   activate: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

Or bind event later on:

```
$( ".selector" ).on( "tabsactivate", function( event, ui ) {} );
```

ONE MORE EDIT:
I created simple JSFiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Bqkst/. And the code here:

HTML

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
</div>
```

​

JS:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
   activate: function( event, ui ) {
       alert( "tab changed" )
   }
});​
```

And each time you clicking tab - alert triggers!

Comment: how to use activate for this function.i refer that link and i implement in this function no solution to find.it was not work.

Comment: if i put the alert inside the function it was not call